# Add menu item to Adobe Acrobat with C#

Tags: c#, plugins, acrobat

I need to create an Adobe Acrobat plug-in that adds a new menu item to the File menu which saves the current file to a Document Management System (presumably via a temp directory). I have been hunting around through Adobe's documentation but I'm not sure how to do this with C# or if it is even possible.

Can anyone offer any advice or point me to a working sample for adding a menu item with C#? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it is possible, as per my understanding Plugins for Adobe acrobat can be developed using C / C++. You can try PInovke.

Comment: Which document management system are you trying to integrate ?

Comment: It seems that it is possible to access the Adobe SDK with .Net - "it is possible to access Acrobat’s JavaScript object model through the OLE Automation JSObject interface". I don't know if I can create menu items though.

Comment: @Alex I am integrating with HP TRIM. I have that side of things down-pat with C#. I would attempt C++ but I don't have time to learn it well enough to have something fit for a production environment.

Comment: I'm sorry I have no knowledge about HP TRIM (I honestly never heard about it), I know for a fact that Acrobat/AcroReader X natively integrate with Sharepoint, maybe you could start from there and check out if something similar can be made up...

Comment: The TRIM side of things is no problem at all; let's pretend I didn't mention that :) I just need to know whether or not it is possible to add a menu item to the File menu in Acrobat and access the open PDF file via C#, possibly through the "OLE Automation JSObject interface".